# Css-Grid: Trouble defining grid rules

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

Using CSS Grid, I'm trying to create a layout that looks like this:

[image]

How do I place the bottom (smaller) elements beyond the first row without using nested elements? The number of smaller elements can be anything. I tried using `grid-auto-columns: 2fr;` to accomplish my task, but it does not work.

Here's what I've tried so far: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QORzbw)

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  grid-template: 1fr/repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "a a a b b b";
  grid-auto-columns: 2fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

main .a {
  grid-area: a;
}

main .b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.cat {
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.cat:hover {
  background-color: #004800;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="cat a"></div>
  <div class="cat b"></div>
  <div class="cat c"></div>
  <div class="cat d"></div>
  <div class="cat e"></div>
  <div class="cat f"></div>
  <div class="cat g"></div>
  <div class="cat h"></div>
  <div class="cat i"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-css-grid-beats-bootstrap-85d5881cf163) is a nice blog post in medium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I did is define how many columns the grid should be. Looking at your image, it made sense to me to go with 12 columns.

[image]

In the `main` element, I add the rule:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
```

In your `.cat` rules, I added a few things. By default, each block takes up 4/12 columns.

```
grid-column: span 4;
```

The last part was dealing with the first two `.cat` blocks, `a` and `b`. No problem. They each take up 6/12 columns.

```
 &.a,
 &.b {
   grid-column: span 6;
 }
```

And that's it. Here's a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8ypuhf00/).

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.cat {
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.cat:hover {
  background-color: #004800;
}

.cat.a,
.cat.b {
  grid-column: span 6;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="cat a"></div>
  <div class="cat b"></div>
  <div class="cat c"></div>
  <div class="cat d"></div>
  <div class="cat e"></div>
  <div class="cat f"></div>
  <div class="cat g"></div>
  <div class="cat h"></div>
  <div class="cat i"></div>
</main>
```